# How to expand the android graphical layout screen size?

Tags: android

In my graphical layout, it cuts off at the end of the screen, even if I have a scrollview set up. Is there a way to expand the graphical layout so that I can see the entire scrollview and not just limited to the screen size?

xml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutChampions"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: check if you have added margin/padding somewhere. it would be nice if you can attach screenshot as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ScrollView` is cropped by `RelativeLayout`'s height, even though it's set to `wrap_layout`. Depends on the layout requirement, you probably don't need a container for `ScrollView`. If that's the case, remove `layoutChampions` and set `ScrollView` as the root. This will make the preview screen ignore the height limit, and let you see the full layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        ...

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

If you need a container for your `ScrollView` and some other `View`s, you probably want to have larger (higher) preview screen. You can create custom device as the workaround.

- Open "Android Virtual Device Manager" (In Eclipse, accessible from "Window" menu)
- Go to "Device Definitions" tab
- Select any device you want, and press "Clone..." (You can create from scratch, too)
- Change the height resolution to some large value (e.g. 4096px). You may also change the name to prevent confusion in the future
- Press "Clone Device"

As the custom device has been created, you can now select it on the preview screen. (Restart Eclipse if it doesn't appear).

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

There's no way to Scroll ScrollView in Eclipse Graphical Layout. However you can do one of following things.

Create a Previewer with Large Screen and see your whole content.

Comment: There could be something else in the code as well. But If your root layout has width and height match_parent only then it will take whole screen size.

Comment: Not sure if I am miscommunicating, but what I want to do is this: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/graphics-layout.jpg

Comment: what I have is just a regular sized screen, like this: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/scroll-view.jpg in the graphical layout

Comment: Still don't get it. If there are more items than size of your screen then they will go down the screen and you can scroll down to see them. What's the problem?

Comment: They will indeed go down the screen and I can scroll down, but only in the emulator. When I am in the graphical layout, I can't scroll down and so I can't see the items that's extended over the screen

Comment: How would I make the previewer?